Evil queen uses crane to dip slaves in liquid gold for statues
I saw this scene briefly in the mid-80s and for some reason it's stuck in my head ever since.  
There's an explorer.  He finds himself in a cave, where this evil lady is driving a light crane which lifts people over a pool of liquid gold.  She lowers them in and pulls them out, and then they're frozen solid into a statue.
That's all I remember.  Any ideas?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.
